# How i implement Debug for trait object

Tags: rust, transactions, client

I find out 1 piece of code in substrate

```
pub struct IsValidator(Box<dyn Fn() -> bool + Send + Sync>);
```

How can I implement Debug for `IsValidator` Struct

Comment: I think you should ask this on StackOverflow Rust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fn traits do not come with `Debug` constraints as such you cannot derive `Debug` on it. You could write a derive implementation for this struct but I doubt it would be useful as you are still missing information on the inner `Fn` type. You may however implement debug with the return type of the `dyn Fn` as it does implement `Debug` in this case.

```rust
struct IsValidator(Box<dyn Fn() -> bool + Send + Sync >);
use std::fmt::{Debug, Error, Formatter};
impl Debug for IsValidator {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), Error> {
         f
        .debug_struct("IsValidator")
        .field("Fn Results", &self.0())
        .finish()
    }
}
    
fn main() {
    let a : IsValidator = IsValidator(Box::new(|| true));
    println!("{a:?}");
}
```

prints `IsValidator { Fn Results : true }`